# Manage data table from a few data sources

Tags: python, dataframe

I am collecting data from a few sources for my data science project. Please take a note that it is a representative data source As Input

Data source 1 (Currently stored as a list of strings)

####Player personal details####

```
Player X
'Age', '35'
'Home', 'Agrentina'
'Money', '100'

Player Y
'Age', '34'
'Home', 'Brazil'
'Money', '4M'

Player Z
'Age', '24'
'Home', 'India'
'Money', '10000'
```

Data source 2 Currently stored in a CSV and a Dataframe in my code for loop

####Player Match Detail Battign ####

```
Player X
Bating
             Run Dismisal
    Match 13, 120, Bowled, 
    Match 22, 19, stamping,
    Match 31, 15, Bowled,

Player Y
Batting

             Run Dismisal
    Match 56, 60, stamping, 
    Match 65, 19, stamping,
    Match 29, 15, Bowled,
```

Data source 3 Currently stored in a CSV and a Dataframe in my code for loop

####Player Match Detail BOWLING ####

```
Player X
 Bowling

           Ball, Run rate, Type, Description
    Match 43, 120, 7.5,Fast, Boweld fast; Pace High; Yorker; 
    Match 42, 19, 48.5,Spin, Bowled off break; Yorker; 
    Match 41, 15, 38.5,Fast, Yorker; Bowled slow;

Player Z
 Bowling

           Ball, Run rate, Type, Description
    Match 51, 60, 9.4, Fast, Boweld fast; Pace High; Yorker; 
    Match 40, 48, 92.2, Fast, Yorker; Bowled slow;
```

####Output#####

**How can I have a folwing format database to show specific player data easily?**

```
 Player Name, Age Home Money, 'No of Math BATED,' 'No of Match BOWLED,' 'Highest Mode of Dismissal,' 'Highest Mode of Dismissal.' "Show Most common two string"
Player X 35 Argentina 100 3 3 Bowled 
Player Y 34 Brazil 4M 3 0 stamping
Player Z 24 India 10000 0 2 Nil
```

[image]

Comment: Please show your actual CSV data. It is hard to know what the column headers are

Comment: Can you please indicate where it is confusing? Or can you show me an example that I can follow to rearrange these tables?